# Convert Pandas DataFrame to dictionairy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple `DataFrame`:

```
      Name Format
0    cntry    int
1  dweight    str
2  pspwght    str
3  pweight    str
4   nwspol    str
```

I want a dictionairy as such:

```
{
    "cntry":"int",
    "dweight":"str",
    "pspwght":"str",
    "pweight":"str",
    "nwspol":"str"
}
```

Where `dict["cntry"]` would return `int` or `dict["dweight"]` would return `str`.

How could I do this?

Comment: I forgot to ask: Why do you need to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'col_2': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'col_3': ['Bla', 'Foo', 'Sup', 'Asdf']})

res_dict = dict(zip(df['col_1'], df['col_3']))
```

Contents of `res_dict`:

```py
{'A': 'Bla', 'B': 'Foo', 'C': 'Sup', 'D': 'Asdf'}
```

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light You’re welcome! Could you edit your answer? I, like many of the people here, misread your question, and by the time I understood my mistake my downvote was locked in D:

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `DataFrame.to_dict()`

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2],
...                    'col2': [0.5, 0.75]},
...                   index=['row1', 'row2'])
>>> df
      col1  col2
row1     1  0.50
row2     2  0.75
>>> df.to_dict()
{'col1': {'row1': 1, 'row2': 2}, 'col2': {'row1': 0.5, 'row2': 0.75}}
```

You can always invert an internal dictionary if it's not mapped how you'd like it to be:

```
inv_dict = {v: k for k, v in original_dict['Name'].items()}
```

Comment: `to_dict()` returns this: `{'Name': {0: 'cntry', 1: 'dweight', 2: 'pspwght', 3: 'pweight', 4: 'nwspol'}, 'Format': {0: 'int', 1: 'str', 2: 'str', 3: 'str', 4: 'str'}}` which is not a useful dictionary in my case. Trying to do `dict["cntry"]` does not work.

Comment: Trying your edit gives `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`.

Comment: Don't invert the whole dictionary invert `original['Name']`

Comment: Now `inv_dict["cntry"]` simply gives the index, I wanted the value `int` this is not quite it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want is:

```
df.set_index('Name').to_dict()['Format']
```

Since you want to use the values in the `Name` column as the keys to your dict.

Note that you might want to do:

```
df.set_index('Name').astype(str).to_dict()['Format']
```

if you want the values of the dictionary to be strings.

Comment: Trying `df["cntry"]` after `df.set_index('Name').astype(str).to_dict()` gives `KeyError: 'cntry'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a part, see the edited answer. You need to add `['Format']` after the `.to_dict()`